# Django 1.5.5: Redirect ignores locale

Tags: python, django, redirect, locale, django-1.5

I'm new to Django and working on a project here at work where there is that little problem I can't seem to find a fix for:

I got my project accessible by using `localhost:8000/`. This URL redirects to `localhost:8000/en/dimension/`. `/en/` being the default locale of my browser so it's all good.

But the problem is, `localhost:8000/fr/` still redirects to `/en/dimension/` and same goes for `/nl/`.

Here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import admin


from opendataApp.views import dimensionStep, productStep, zoneStep, formatStep, geographicalAreaStep, customStep, downloadStep, proxy, downloadCustom, statistics, statisticsReset, statisticsFilter

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^proxy/urbis/(?P<path>.*)$', proxy),
    #translation
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    '',

    url(r'^$', lambda r: redirect('/dimension/'), name="home"),
    url(r'^dimension', dimensionStep, name="dimensionStep"),
    url(r'^product', productStep, name="productStep"),
    url(r'^zone', zoneStep, name="zoneStep"),
    url(r'^format', formatStep, name="formatStep"),
    url(r'^selection', geographicalAreaStep, name="geographicalAreaStep"),
    url(r'^custom-selection', customStep, name="custom"),
    url(r'^download/$', downloadStep, name="download"),
    url(r'^download-custom/$', downloadCustom, name="downloadCustom"),
    url(r'^statistics/$', statistics, name="statistics"),
    url(r'^statistics/reset$', statisticsReset, name="statisticsReset"),
    url(r'^statistics/filter$', statisticsFilter, name="statisticsFilter"),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),

)
```

So my main issue is that `redirect('/dimension/')` ignores the previously asked locale and falls back to default locale again. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the [`LocaleMiddleware` middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) installed?

Comment: Yes, I do: 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LocaleMiddleware` is responsible for determining what language the browser should be served; it is consistently picking `en` for your browser, and you need to figure out why.

See [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) for the details, but the short order is:

1. look at the path prefix; for `/` and `/dimension/` there isn't one yet.
2. look for a `_language` key in the session (falling back to `django_language` for backwards compatibility).
3. look for a `django_language` cookie (or whatever you set in `settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME`)
4. look at the browser `Accept-Language` header
5. use `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`.

Note that *nothing* sets the session key or cookie explicitly; your own code needs to do so. You can use the [`set_language()` redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) to do this for you; a form in your web UI would POST to that view to let a visitor set a different language.

You can also set the session key or cookie explicitly when a visitor comes to `/fr/` and doesn't yet have an explicit cookie or session key. You'd do so in a view attached to `^$` in the `i18n_patterns()` url map (which is called for any `/<language_code>/` request), instead of the redirect you have now. That view can still redirect, of course.

Even without explicitly setting the cookie, your redirect should at the very least use the `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` variable:

```
url(r'^$', lambda r: redirect('/{}/dimension/'.format(r.LANGUAGE_CODE)), name="home"),
```

Comment: How can I catch the simple /fr/ url and put anything into a cookie/session or what ever? Why does the following not work? `url(r'^fr/', lambda r: redirect('fr/dimension/'), name="home"),`

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: You cannot add that to the `i18n_patterns` because it'll *already* pull in a `/language` prefix. Matching `^fr/` means `/en/fr`, etc.

Comment: So there's no way to know what locale the user is asking for when processing patterns ?

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: Updated the answer a little. Any `url(r'^fr/')` pattern would have to be declared as a regular url map, *not* in the `i18n_patterns()` map.

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: If a user explicitly asks for `/fr/` then `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` will be set to `fr`. But redirecting to `/dimension/` will *not* include a language code. Create a view for `^$` that redirects to `/<request.LANGUAGE_CODE>/dimension`.

Comment: There you go! You solved it! Your version of the redirect works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache? Browsers often cache redirects.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem. I have cleared everything and still redirects to the default locale. I have tried with a french based browser and it always redirects to /fr/dimension/. Here I have an english based browser so it always redirects to /en/dimension/. It has to be something else than cache I guess.